# Let $K$ be midpoint of the hypotenuse of a right triangle $ABC$.On the leg $AB$ is a point $M$ s.t $BM=2MC$.Show that $MAB$ and $MKC$ are similar.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $K$ be the midpoint of the hypotenuse of a right triangle $\triangle ABC$. 
On the leg $BC$ is a point $M$ such that $ BM = 2MC$ .
 Prove that the triangles $\triangle MAB$ and $\triangle MKC$ similar .

My work:
We know that $2*BK=AB$, $2*AK=AB$
If $\triangle MAB$ and $\triangle MKC$ are similar . Then we know $$\frac{MA}{MK}=\frac{AB}{KC}=\frac{MB}{MC}=k$$
I only know this: $\frac{MB}{MC}=\frac{2MC}{MC}=2=k$

Comment: This is unclear. If $M$ is on $AB$, then $MAB$ is not a triangle. Which side of $ABC$ is the hypotenuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

We have $\frac{MB}{MC}=2=\frac{BA}{CK}$ (because $K$ is the centre of the circle $ABC$).Also $\angle MBA=\angle MCK$ because triangle $KBC$ is isosceles.